# Which design pattern to use while refactoring two classes containing half related and half unrelated functions?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have two objects, **Bird** and **Dog**. **Bird** and **Dog** have identical implementations for about 50% of methods/properties but different **unrelated**  methods and properties for the other 50%.

I'm refactoring and I don't know what is the best strategy.

I tried defining a superclass **Animal** to implement common methods in the superclass and let the children classes define their own methods/properties.

I wrote a factory that returned one or the other - this all seems right... but I'm confused when writing the calling code.. e.g.

```
public class Animal{
   public string Talk(){ return "yak yak yak";
}
public class Dog:Animal{
   public string Walk(){ return "walk walk walk"; }
}
public class Bird:Animal{
   public string Fly(){ return "flap flap flap"; }
}
...
Animal thing = CreatureFactory.GetCreature(modifier);
```

When I want to use **thing** to **Talk** there's no problem,

```
Debug.Print(thing.Talk());
```

but what about when as the programmer I know I want it to **Fly** do I cast it to **Bird**? That seems wrong... but defining a **Fly** method on **Dog** seems wrong too.

Comment: Why don't you just declare thing as a bird if you want it to fly?

Comment: Think about this: How do you know you have a Bird? Why do you want it to `Fly()`. Probably because some Input satisfied some conditions right? Your Animals need to `DoSomethingWith(Input)`. Birds and Dogs should implement as they see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, when you want your `Animal` to fly, the class doing the flying is working with the wrong class -- it should be using the `Bird` itself or some `ICanFly` interface.

While the other answers said you *can* do it with casting, the readability of your code will suffer because of it.  When you have factories creating your objects, there's absolutely no reason you should be casting those objects to another type.  There's also a solid argument that your classes are violating the Single Responsibility Principle when you start casting to other types.

Answer (score 3):

You either cast it to a bird:

```
Debug.Print(((Bird)thing).Fly());
```

or you treat it as a bird the whole time:

```
// depending on how the factory works, might not need the cast
Bird thing = (Bird) CreatureFactory.GetCreature(modifier);
Debug.Print(bird.Fly());
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach it is to have the factory method return a concrete type rather than the superclass.  You can still pass it to methods that can operate on the superclass, but you have an item of the concrete class to work with when needed and don't need to cast it.

```
Bird bird = CreatureFactory.GetBird();
```

or

```
Dog dog = CreatureFactory.GetDog();
```

Now, you can still use them as an `Animal`.

```
public class Trainer
{
     public void TeachToSpeak( Animal animal )
     {
          ...
          animal.Talk();
     }
}
```

But since they are typed to the concrete class, you can make use of the methods they don't share as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:
if your dog has also a methods that gives the idea of "movement", I would change the name of fly and walk to "move" and then call it.
If your dog doesn't have anything like that, the dev shouldn't be able to call it on an anymal object, because not all animals can fly :)

Comment: That's not a bad thought, except that many birds can also walk.

Comment: @MattBall: So provide a 3D vector and a 3D grid. Now you can check if it's flying or not.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, I would put a virtual method on the base class called `Move()` and override it in the derived classes.

**(The following is C#)**

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public string Talk() { return "yak yak yak"; }
   public virtual string Move();
}
public class Dog : Animal {
   public override string Move() { return "walk walk walk"; }
}
public class Bird : Animal {
   public override string Move() { return "flap flap flap"; }
}
```

But to answer your question, if you want the animal to move if (and only if) it can fly, you could define an `IFlyingAnimal` interface and implement it with `Bird`. Then you can test whether an `Animal` implements that interface. If it does, cast it to `IFlyingAnimal` and call its `Fly()` method.

```
public interface IFlyingAnimal {
   string Fly();
}
public class Bird : Animal, IFlyingAnimal {
   public string Fly(){ return "flap flap flap"; }
}

//later, in your main program
public string FlyIfYouCan(Animal animal) {
    if (animal is IFlyingAnimal)
        return ((IFlyingAnimal)animal).Fly();

    return "I can't fly!";
}
```

You don't *have* to use an interface; you could just use `if (animal is Bird)` instead. But it's much better practice to do it this way; birds aren't the only animals that can fly, so you're making the decision based on what your item **does**, not what it **is**. That's what interfaces are for.